# JOGL with Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, jogl

I am new to JOGL. I have studied about `AWT` and `Swing` in java. I have studied that mixing of AWT and Swing (heavywaight and lightwaight components) is not good and give unpredictable results. I have studied about JOGL with swing from [here](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing).
But `GLCanvas` class is AWT component and `GLJPanel` is slow in performance. So I want to know that which `API` I have to use with JOGL while maintaining good performance.

Comment: Mixing Heavy- and Lightweight components is tricky indeed. You should read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html (it should actually work well, but there may always be glitches...). The appropriate solution depends partially on the *kind* of application you are writing. If you have a "main OpenGL component" and (separate of that) a bunch of "control components", then you should use a `GLCanvas` as the main component, and Swing for the control components: The main problems with mixing happen when the components *overlap*, which is most often not the case

Answer (score 1):

You can put a GLCanvas into a JPanel except in some particular cases (with JInternalFrame), when you need translucent components and there can be some problems when overlapping as Marco13 wrote. JOGL has its own windowing toolkit since its second major version, it's called NEWT, you can use it with AWT, SWT and Swing, it's the best in terms of performance:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_FAQ#How_to_use_Newt_with_multiple_Windows_.26_Threads

GLJPanel isn't slow in general, it is less fast than GLCanvas, it is really slow on some combinations of hardware and operating systems.